Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MailService (?)
I created a mail module that will be used to handle sending emails, but after setting to up, I keep getting an error message when I tried starting the app:
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MailService (?). Please make sure that the argument Function at index [0] is available in the MailModule context.  Potential solutions: - Is MailModule a valid NestJS module? - If Function is a provider, is it part of the current MailModule? - If Function is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within MailModule?   @Module({     imports: [ /* the Module containing Function */ ]   })
Here's my MailModule:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HandlebarsAdapter } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/adapters/handlebars.adapter';
import { MailerModule } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

import { join } from 'node:path';
import { MailService } from './mail.service';
import { MailController } from './mail.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        transport: {
          host: configService.get<string>('SMTP_HOST'),
          port: configService.get<number>('SMTP_PORT'),
          auth: {
            user: configService.get<string>('SMTP_USER'),
            pass: configService.get<string>('SMTP_PASSWORD'),
          },
        },
        defaults: {
          from: `"No Reply" <${configService.get<string>('SMTP_USER')}>`,
        },
        template: {
          dir: join(__dirname, 'templates'),
          adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
          options: {
            strict: true,
          },
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [MailService],
  exports: [MailService],
  controllers: [MailController],
})
export class MailModule {}

And here's the MailService:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import type { MailerService } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';

@Injectable()
export class MailService {
  constructor(private readonly mailerService: MailerService) {}

  async sendMail(to: string, subject: string, template: string, context: any) {
    await this.mailerService.sendMail({
      to,
      subject,
      template,
      context,
    });
  }
}

Checked the documentation, but nothing seems to work.

In your second code block, you are importing "type { MailerService }". Try removing the word "type".
Here is the example I referred to.
